# Rock Paper Scissors game gone wrong

Tags: c#

Console app rock paper scissors game well i have trouble explaining it you just have to test it and see also whenever i press y it's suppose to clear the console and start the game over but that is just 1/2 the problem whenever i type 'rock' it translates it to 'ock' same with paper and scissor it takes out the first letter.

```
  enum Rock_Paper_Scissor
{
    rock,
    paper,
    scissor
}
class Computer
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    public Rock_Paper_Scissor Choice()
    {
        Rock_Paper_Scissor element = (Rock_Paper_Scissor)rand.Next(3);
        return element;
    }

}


class  Game_Logic
{

    static void Main()
    {
        Computer Comp = new Computer();
        bool PlayAgain = true;
        ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();
        Rock_Paper_Scissor ComputerChoice = Comp.Choice();


           do
           {
               string PlayerChoice = Console.ReadLine();
               Console.Clear();

            while (PlayerChoice == ComputerChoice.ToString())
            {
                ComputerChoice = Comp.Choice();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Player: "+ PlayerChoice);
            Console.WriteLine("Computer: " + ComputerChoice);

            if (PlayerChoice == "rock" && ComputerChoice.ToString() == "scissor")

                Console.WriteLine("You won!");

            else if (PlayerChoice == "scissor" && ComputerChoice.ToString() == "rock")

                Console.WriteLine("Computer won!");

            else if (PlayerChoice == "paper" && ComputerChoice.ToString() == "rock")

                Console.WriteLine("You won!");

            else if (PlayerChoice == "rock" && ComputerChoice.ToString() == "paper")

                Console.WriteLine("Computer won");

            else if (PlayerChoice == "scissor" && ComputerChoice.ToString() == "paper")

                Console.WriteLine("You won!");

            else if (PlayerChoice == "paper" && ComputerChoice.ToString() == "scissor")

                Console.WriteLine("Computer won!");
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("invalid value");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n"+"Play again? <y/n>");

            PlayAgain = input.KeyChar == 'y';

            } while (PlayAgain);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ConsoleKeyInfo input = Console.ReadKey();
Rock_Paper_Scissor ComputerChoice = Comp.Choice();
do
{
    string PlayerChoice = Console.ReadLine();
```

The issue lies with this snippet. Your first letter will be eaten triggering the first `Console.Readkey` meaning the `Console.ReadLine()` you are intending to pass the value too will only receive the rest.

The `Console.ReadKey()` line will do you no good outside the `do` loop anyway, you may as well remove it and do

```
///
Console.WriteLine("\n"+"Play again? <y/n>");
} while (Console.ReadKey.KeyChar == 'y');
```

Directly. Solving both problems.

Comment: Can you please word that differently. Because I don't understand.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Nevermind, i fully understand what you are saying now.  It's due to my inexperience with using Console.ReadKey() and Console.Clear() that i stumbled on this issue.